# Java Try Catch error

Tags: java, try-catch

This is homework. I added what I thought was a simple try-catch statement to ensure the user enters a double. As soon as I do I get a compiler error that "radius cannot be resolved to a variable" I'm sure its something obvious, but I'm not getting it. What do I need to do to validate that the input is a valid, positive number?

```
import javax.swing.*;

//Driver class
public class CylinderTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean valid = false;

        Cylinder[] volume = new Cylinder[3];

                for (int counter = 0; counter < volume.length; counter++)
                {
                    //user input
                    try
                    {
                    double radius = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the radius"));
                    }

                    catch (NumberFormatException e)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Error. Please enter a valid number", "Error",
                                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    double height = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the height"));
                    volume[counter] = new Cylinder(radius, height);
                }

        for (int i = 0; i < volume.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("for Radius of:" + volume[i].getRadius()
                    + " and Height of:" + volume[i].getHeight()
                    + " the Volume is:" + volume[i].volume());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to declare `radius` in a larger scope.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Actually, I think it would make more sense to put the references to `radius` and `height` within the `try` block.

Comment: yes i too thought of moving the radius reference to try block and adding one more catch block for other exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of the radius variable ends in the try block. Declare the radius outside.

```
 for (int counter = 0; counter < volume.length; counter++){
           //user input
     try{
          double radius = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the radius"));
          double height = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the height"));
          volume[counter] = new Cylinder(radius, height);
     }catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Error. Please enter a valid number", "Error",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
```

Comment: This would resolve the compile error, but the behavior would be odd.

Comment: @FredLarson: Yes, I am including the other way also which you suggested in your previous comment. Thanks..

Comment: I see no reason to declare `radius` outside the `try` block in your second example. Also, this `volume[counter] = new Cylinder(radius, height);` line is unnecessary duplicated.

Comment: @Dibya Thanks. That was exactly the problem. What if I declared the variable at main? what is the better programming practice?

Comment: @Elist: Copy paste resulted in duplicate line and declaration of radius outside of try block. ;)

Comment: @user2802785: If you declare the variable in main then the variable will live throughout the program, which is not required. Here you have only one variable but if the size increases, then PermGen will be out of memory and you will start getting error message as PermGen out of memory error.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework, I will not give you the answer outright.  You need to look at where you declare `radius` and how the **location of that declaration affects the visibility** of the variable in other blocks of your code.  Where you declare these variables is critical and something you should work through as part of your class.  You are close, the answer is right in front of you.  :)

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something obvious, but I just couldn't see it. Thanks again